# How to capture the tick event of the task checkbox on 'Outlook Today'? VSTO Add-in

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm developing an Outlook Add-in, and currently I have no idea on how to capture the task's checkbox (mark complete) tick event -- particularly on the 'Outlook Today' view. I'd like to override it with my own function.

Refer to the attached image as reference to the checkbox being referred to.

[Outlook Today Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw9ic.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook Today page is not a typical area that can be integrated with.  It is possible though, as it is basically an .html page; see: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc750169.aspx.  However, this is 20 year-old technology...

If you are mainly interested in trapping changes to that task, then you can trap the Items.ItemAdd event for the Tasks folder and do whatever you like with the modified Task.

Comment: yes, you're right - that it's just an html page. I actually didn't consider the Outlook Today page when I was doing the initial dev't. But since the project I am doing has outlook tasks involved.. the users assumed that they could do anything where the tasks are present - in that sense, it's on the Outlook Today page. :(
Anyway, thanks for the advice - i'll look into these and give you feedback. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for the Outlook Today page. It just lists items from your folders. So, you may consider handling the following events to get the job done:

- The [ItemChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865866.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event of the Items class which is fired when an item in the specified collection is changed.
- The [PropertyChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866739.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event of Outlook items which is fired when an explicit built-in property of an object is changed.

Both events are fired when you mark the task as completed. But in case of the `PropertyChange` event you need to subscribe to each task item individually which is not really convenient.